# How to get Eclipse Tomcat configuration folder path?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing, tomcat

I am running a unit test on a method that reads an environment entry from `web.xml` in Eclipse Tomcat configuration folder. How can I get the file path for Eclipse Tomcat configuration folder `web.xml` in that test?

Comment: Your unit test depends on running in Eclipse? That is not a good approach.

Comment: @Pavel Horal, what do you suggest ?

Comment: Well unit tests should not depend on anything, if you ask me. Maybe describe what you are trying to achieve and someone might suggest solution for you or a better alternative approach.

Comment: This question can be closed as "Needs Details/Clarity".